If $X$ and $Y$ are two $n$-manifolds that glued along a common disk are an $n$-ball, then both are $n$-balls
We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are topological $n$-manifolds with connected boundary.
Assume $D_X \subseteq \partial X$ and $D_Y \subseteq \partial Y$ are disks of dimension $n-1$ that are contained in the boundaries.
We let $X \oplus Y$ be the $n$-manifold obtained from gluing $X$ and $Y$ along their common disk $D_X$ and $D_Y$.
This looks similar to the connected sum of two manifolds without boundary, except that the latter glues manifolds along two interior balls, whereas I am interested in glueing manifolds along boundary disks.
This seems to define an "addition" operation on $n$-manifolds with connected boundary. It is essential that the boundary is connected. This operation is commutative and associative, and the $n$-ball is the neutral element.

Are there any references for this type of operation?

I am interested most in the case that $X \oplus Y$ is a ball. Does it follow that $X$ and $Y$ are balls. In other words, the neutral element can only be the sum of neutral elements?




It is called "boundary connected sum," you can find many references by googling (or using your favorite search engine). The usual notation is $X\#_\partial Y$.

Yes, this is a consequence of the Schoenflies theorem. Suppose that  $X\#_\partial Y$ is homeomorphic to the closed $n$-ball $B^n$. Then the $n-1$-dimensional boundary disk $D$ along which we were gluing the manifolds $X$ and $Y$ corresponds to a disk $D\subset B^n$ which has the following properties:



$$
\partial D=D\cap S^{n-1},
$$
is a locally flat $n-2$-dimensional sphere in $S^{n-1}$.

$\partial D$ separates $S^{n-1}$ in two subsets, whose closures are $D_\pm$. They are homeomorphic to $B^{n-1}$ (by Schoenflies theorem).

Both $E_\pm= D\cup D_\pm$ are $n-1$-dimensional topological spheres, which are locally flat in $\mathbb R^n$ (the last part is a bit painful, I do not want to write down a proof).


Hence, by applying Schoenflies theorem to the topological spheres $E_\pm\subset \mathbb R^n$, we see that both bound compact subsets each homeomorphic to $B^n$. These subsets are homeomorphic to $X$ and $Y$. qed
